# F-test for equality of regression coefficients

Tags: regression, anova, multiple-comparisons, references, f-test

I have been trying to look for a reference on the theory behind using the F-test to test for the equality of regression coefficients. The closest I could find is this, which is for general linear restrictions: http://www.mattblackwell.org/files/teaching/ftests.pdf. Google seems to have failed me.

Could you point me in the right direction for a theoretical reference on using F-tests to test for equality of regression coefficients? Thanks a lot in advance!